# Can we view the methods of COM DLL or COM EXE and calling one by one at runtime.(Using Reflections)

Tags: reflection, com

Can we call COM exposed interface methods at runtime one by one? This can be achieved in the case of Win32 DLL's using reflections, but the same job needs to be done with COM.dll or COM.exe. We'll be able to view all exposed methods of that COM.dll or COM.exe and we need to call all of them one by one (Remember, I need to call unmanaged code, purely written in VC++ unmanaged code, that would **not** be .NET assembly).

Regards,

Usman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the target COM object supports the IDispatch interface you could read its typelibrary and call the methods dynamically. But you still need to figure out what to pass should the method take any arguments.

Comment: and what if COM Object suuports IUnknown interface...? 
As my most of COM binaries support only IUnknown interface?

Comment: Well, I don't see why you could not read the component's typelib, instantiate each CoClass, QueryInterface for each implemented interface and iterate over its methods (through vtable) calling one by one. Of course, this approach assumes the components does have a typelib and it will require a some **fun** code.